# Why does my centered variable not have zero mean?

Tags: r, regression, interaction, mean, centering

It is well established that centering a variable, i.e. subtracting the mean of that variable from every value produces a variable with zero mean. For example:

```
> data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
> mean = mean(data)
> data.centered = data-mean
> mean(data.centered)
[1] 0
```

So far, so good. However, an attempt at centering a logged variable from my dataset produces a mean that is close to zero, but not exactly zero:

```
[1] -0.0000000000000004258896
```

This is puzzling. I have two questions:

1) why is the mean not exactly zero?

2) is the fact that the mean is not exactly zero a problem for calculating regression interactions?

Comment: 1. Computers aren't infinite-precision calculation machines.  $1 + 10^{-16} = 1$ in double-precision arithmetic, and your mean looks to be on the order of $10^{-16}$.  2.  No, not unless all the other data has magnitudes on the order of $10^{-13}$ or smaller.

Comment: You are using a sixteen-digit calculator to produce a twenty-two digit value.  I wonder how many of those digits make any sense.

Comment: `help(".Machine")`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a result of a numerical error. Computers have limited precision and such errors are normal. It is easy to understand if you realize how mean is computed:

```
sum = 0
for i = 0..N
    sum += data[i]
mean = sum / N
```

Assuming we are talking about floating point numbers, which are stored in the memory as an exponent and a mantissa. As you sum numbers, the variable `sum` becomes large and its exponent grows. It can happen that the numbers `data[i]` you are adding are simply too small to change the mantissa anymore. This is a common source of the numerical errors.

Another thing is that many numbers cannot be expressed exactly in the computers (for example `0.1`).

For better explanation on how numerical errors work see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100502/2042751)

Practically, such a small error as the number you posted should not cause problems for you, unless your data are of the same small magnitude (as pointed out in the comment of @jbowman).